# Paypal Recurrent Payments breakdown

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am working with Paypal recurrent payments with NVP protocol and C# ASP MVC 4, but I think my question is valid for everybody working with paypal and recurring payments.

Are there any way to see the breakdown of a recurrent-payment ?

I mean, suppose today is 2013/01/01 and I set a recurrent payment with `PROFILESTARTDATE` set to **2013/02/01** and in this way :

1. Initial amount: 10€
2. Trial amount: 5€ - 3 monthly periods.
3. Subscription amount: 10€ - infinite monthly periods.

I would like to get a `planning` of my payments only to check all is rightly understood by paypal and I have not sending any confusing or erroneus data, more or less in this way:

```
 
 2013/01/01 - 10 € (initial)
 2013/02/01 -  5 € (trial) 
 2013/03/01 -  5 € (trial) 
 2013/04/01 -  5 € (trial) 
 2013/05/01 - 10 € (subscription)
 2013/06/01 - 10 € (subscription)
 2013/07/01 - 10 € (subscription)
 2013/08/01 - 10 € (subscription)
 2013/09/01 - 10 € (subscription)
 .....
```

All of this with amount, taxes, item information and so on.

Any idea if this information can be obtained and how can I do it with the paypal-sandbox or with paypal-api-nvp ?

The paypal information for the test-user inside the sandbox is not giving me this information or I cannot find it.